# Fixed Double pane window temporary repair

Tags: repair, windows, glass, temporary

Shattered the exterior side of a fixed double pane window. Is it possible to remove the remaining pieces of the broken pane without the interior side falling out? Every glass company around is booked for at least a month and I’m looking for a temporary fix until I can get a new unit installed. [image]

Comment: I guess a better question would be do double pane windows usually hold themselves in the frame by just their own thickness? Or is there some sort of adhesion in between frame and window?

Comment: the unbroken pane will not fall out, but it may separate from the frame and allow drafts ... you could dig out the broken pieces, but you may have to insert shims that would prevent the aluminium spacer from moving around if it is not attached to the frame

Comment: Thanks for the replies I found some 1/4 inch trim I have laying around same thickness of the glass I was gonna use to shim it we’ll see how it goes

Comment: you could make a frame out of the 1/4 inch trim and use it to hold a sheet of plastic in the window ... if you do not care about transparency, then put bubblebwrap between the glass and the plastic sheet